# Displaying milliseconds in Attribute Table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, datetime

I have a datetime string with microsecond. I use the following script to get a `QDateTime` object and add it to a memory layer:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "test", "memory")
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("dt", QVariant.DateTime)])
layer.updateFields()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True)

s = "22/04/20 05:14:38:560000" # 560000 microsec = 560 millisec
# PyQt5 doesn't support microsec, so s[:-3]
dt = QDateTime.fromString(s[:-3], "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:zzz").addYears(100)

feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry()) # empty geometry for test
feat["dt"] = dt

layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()
```

But the millisecond part is missing in the attribute table.

[image]

How can I display the millisecond part in attribute table?

I do calculation at the level of milliseconds.

Comment: [This might be of help](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Date/QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter.html). It appears you need to set the DateTime format for the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment by @Matt was already pointing in a correct direction. [`QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Date/QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter.html) is indeed needed to modify the display of `DateTime` values.

The following code example replaces the default `DateTime` formatter within the `QgsFieldFormatterRegistry` with a new formatter. The new formatter uses the given format string to parse any value.

```py
class MyFormatter(QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter):
    
    config = {"display_format": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:zzz"} # your custom date time format
    
    def representValue(self, layer, fieldIndex, config, cache, value):
        return super().representValue(layer, fieldIndex, self.config, cache, value)
        

registry = QgsApplication.fieldFormatterRegistry()
registry.removeFieldFormatter('DateTime')
registry.addFieldFormatter(MyFormatter())
```

[image: date_display]

While writing this answer I just noticed that this approach removes the timezone string. I'm not sure at the moment on how to add it to the formatter.

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments `QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter` formats all `QDateTime`, `QDate` and `QTime` values. In order to only modify the display of a single of those types implement a simple type check as below. `QDate` and `QTime` values should then stay the same.

```py
def representValue(self, layer, fieldIndex, config, cache, value):
        if type(value) == QDateTime:
            return super().representValue(layer, fieldIndex, self.config, cache, value)
        
        return super().representValue(layer, fieldIndex, config, cache, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. Timezone is not necessary. It worked on DateTime format but it also changed only time (QTime) format to `dd/MM/yyyy 10:20:32:000`. It was displayed just `10:20:32` before this solution. I mean, this script adds `dd/MM/yyy` string  and `:000` to QTime value. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lhr1.png

Comment: And it adds `00:00:00:000` to QDate fields. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckjLH.png

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Thanks for the notice. I didn't check other field types. I've updated my answer so that other values won't be modified. https://imgur.com/a/BR2gnnJ