# Exporting layer with datetime field with milliseconds value

Tags: qgis, export, datetime

I have a layer with datetime field with milliseconds. I use the following script to get a `QDateTime` object and add it to a memory layer:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "test", "memory")
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("dt", QVariant.DateTime)])
layer.updateFields()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True)

s = "22/04/20 05:14:38:560"
dt = QDateTime.fromString(s[:-3], "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:zzz").addYears(100)

feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry()) # empty geometry for test
feat["dt"] = dt

layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()
```

[image]

As in the image, although the millisecond part is missing in the attribute table, I can get whole datetime value including milliseconds as follows:

```py
feat = list(iface.activeLayer().getFeatures())[0]
print(feat["dt"])

#                                                     vvv millisecond
# OUT: PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2022, 4, 20, 5, 14, 38, 560)
```

But when I export the layer as CSV or Excel file using "Export > Save Features As...", it doesn't add the milliseconds part to the file:

```
dt,
2022/04/20 05:14:38
```

How can I export the layer to include the milliseconds part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you register a custom formatter as described in my answer on your related question ([Displaying milliseconds in Attribute Table using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431465/displaying-milliseconds-in-attribute-table-using-pyqgis)),
the formatter can be applied to modify the exported datetime values.

In the *Export* > *Save Features As...* menu, tick the option *Use Date/Time* within the *Replace with displayed values* column. QGIS then exports all datetime values exactly as shown in the Attribute Table, therefore including the desired milliseconds part.

[image: check_option]

Resulting in the following file content after export:

```
dt,
20/04/2022 05:14:38:560
```