# Exporting Geopackage converts milliseconds of QDateTime to zero

Tags: qgis, export, geopackage, datetime

I use [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431547/29431) to display actual QDateTime value with milliseconds in a temporary memory layer. And I use [another solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431646/29431) to export as CSV the value including the millisecond value.

[image]

But then, I realized that "Use Date/Time" option changed the type of the `time_break` field from QDateTime to string when I exported as GeoPackage. But I need a datetime field in the GeoPackage.

Export using "Use Date/Time" option:

[image]

Result (converted to string):

[image]

If I don't use "Use Date/Time" option, it exports the field as QDateTime, but it changes all millisecond values to zero:

[image]

How can I export it as a GeoPackage to contain the datetime field with the actual millisecond value?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug? I did not find any way to save this GeoJSON into a new geopackage and keep the fractional seconds. Same thing is I first converted json into geopackage with ogr2ogr that does keep fractional seconds `{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "timestamp",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "1", "timestamp": "2022-05-20T01:02:03.456+01:00" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 47224.476043935123016, 5282390.128387222066522 ] } }
]}`

Comment: Maybe there is some analogy with this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/41213 where the fix was to use `Qt::ISODateWithMs`.