# Changing appearence of DateTime input in QGIS Processing tool to international datetime format

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, datetime, formatting

I am writing a processing tool for QGIS where I use a [`QgsProcessingParameterDateTime`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProcessingParameterDateTime.html) as input. By default it displays the input in a not understandable format (`dd.MM.yy HH:mm`). To keep this input transparent and understandable for everyone, **I would like to display it in international datetime format (`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz:t`)**.

[image]

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterDateTime(
        self.START_DATETIME, self.tr('Start Datetime'), type = QgsProcessingParameterDateTime.DateTime, defaultValue = QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(-31)))
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterDateTime(
        self.END_DATETIME, self.tr('End Datetime'), type = QgsProcessingParameterDateTime.DateTime, defaultValue = QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(-1)))
```

Unfortunately [the docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProcessingParameterDateTime.html) dont mention formatting in a single word. And besides from it, I can only find the [`QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDateTimeFieldFormatter.html), but I am not sure if/how this can be used for `QDateTime` inputs in processing tools (only could find a [related post about attribute table appearence](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431465/displaying-milliseconds-in-attribute-table-using-pyqgis)).

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own widget. The following example (`DateTimeWidget`)  is derived from [this tutorial](https://www.faunalia.eu/en/blog/2019-07-02-custom-processing-widget). But first some imports:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import (
    QCoreApplication,
    QDateTime,
)

from processing.gui.wrappers import WidgetWrapper

from qgis.gui import QgsDateTimeEdit
# from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDateTimeEdit

from qgis.core import (
    Qgis,
    QgsMessageLog,
    QgsProcessingParameterString,
    QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
)

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
```

We then create `DateTimeWidget`. In addition to the tutorial's implementation, we also add a `setValue` method to be able to set a value, otherwise the default value is ignored. We also set the display format with `self._combo.setDisplayFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)`.

```py
DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

class DateTimeWidget(WidgetWrapper):

    def createWidget(self):
        
        self._combo = QgsDateTimeEdit()
        self._combo.setCalendarPopup(True)
       
        self._combo.setDisplayFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)

        today = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self._combo.setDateTime(today)

        return self._combo

    def setValue(self, value):
        self._combo.setDateTime(value)

    def value(self):
        date_chosen = self._combo.dateTime()
        return date_chosen.toString(Qt.ISODate)
```

The following `DateTimeWidgetTest` shows an example implementation of a `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` using `DateTimeWidget`.

(All it does is logging the selected date.)

We create a `QgsProcessingParameterString` instead of `QgsProcessingParameterDateTime` and then set the wrapper with `param.setMetadata({'widget_wrapper': {"class": DateTimeWidget}})`.

```py
class DateTimeWidgetTest(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    DATE_SELECTION = "DATE_SELECTION"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("Processing", string)

    def name(self):
        return "PrintDateTime"
    
    def displayName(self):
        return "Prints a datetime string"
    
    def group(self):
        return "Example Scripts"
    
    def groupId(self):
        return "playground"
        
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        
        param = QgsProcessingParameterString(
            self.DATE_SELECTION,
            self.tr("Date Selection"),
            defaultValue=QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(-31),
            optional=False
        )
        
        param.setMetadata({'widget_wrapper': {"class": DateTimeWidget}})
        
        self.addParameter(param)
    
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        datetime = self.parameterAsDateTime(
            parameters,
            self.DATE_SELECTION,
            context
        );
        
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(datetime), level=Qgis.Info)
        
        return {}
```

---

[image]

---

**Resources:**

- [Custom Processing (Date Time) Widget](https://www.faunalia.eu/en/blog/2019-07-02-custom-processing-widget)
- [`PySide2.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat)
- [`qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsDateTimeEdit.html)
- [`qgis.gui.QgsDateTimeEdit`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsDateTimeEdit.html)